# Dokan Plugin Template customization with custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, templates, dokan

I have a website where I want to customize the templates of multi vendor plugin `dokan-lite`.

I want to modify that template `tmpl-add-product-popup` into my custom plugin I have used that with child theme. It works fine but I want to do it with Custom plugin due to my plan.

Also I tried `dokan_locate_template` hook, but its not working.

I have tried that hook:

```php
add_filter('dokan_locate_template', [$this, 'extend_dokan_locate_template'], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually used Dokan enough to have specific experience with `dokan-lite`, but I *have* done what you're trying to do with general theme and plugin template files. The most common "gotcha" I've run into has been load order; the order which hooks are processed does make a difference. Ensure that you are adding your filter *after* the one included in `dokan-lite`.